# React Native Expo: How to query select fields from multiple documents in a collection with Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am currently trying to use Firebase to sync my listings of pets on my application so that it can be displayed as such:

(IMAGE)
Name Breed Age
Shelter

[image]

However, I am having difficulty trying to code this out as I am only able to query from one document as shown in the code below:

```
    db.collection("pets").doc("dog01").get()
        .then(doc => {
              console.log(doc.data());
              this.setState({ 
                name: doc.data().name,
                shelter: doc.data().shelter,
                gender: doc.data().gender,
                age: doc.data().age,
                breed: doc.data().breed,
              });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        });
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the documents from collection, then display inside component's render (are you using Class Component's, right?).

Firstly, don't forget to declare the `state`:

```js
state = {
  pets: []
}
```

The method to query every cutie pet:

```js
async getPets() {
  const snapshot = await db.collection("pets").get()
  const pets = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

  this.setState({ pets });
}
```

Call fetch method when component mount on screen:

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  this.getPets();
}
```

Inside render, you only need to map each document to display:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      { this.state.pets.map(pet => (
        <View>
          <Text>{ pet.name }</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text>{ pet.shelter }</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text>{ pet.gender }</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text>{ pet.age }</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text>{ pet.breed }</Text>
        </View>
      )) }
    </View>
  );
}
```